# Cubic identity involving the angles of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

If $A+B+C=180^\circ$, then prove that

> $$\sin^3A+\sin^3B+\sin^3C=3\cos\frac{A}{2}\,\cos\frac{B}{2}\,\cos\frac{C}{2}+\cos\frac{3A}{2}\,\cos\frac{3B}{2}\,\cos\frac{3C}{2}$$

I could only get:
$A+B+C=\pi$ and $A+B=\pi-C$. After this, I don't get enough idea to solve.

Comment: HINT: Use $sin^3A=\frac{3sinA-sin3A}{4}$

Comment: The three-fold product-to-sum identities would come in handy: $$\sin x \sin y \sin z = \frac{1}{4} \left( - \sin(x+y+z) + \sin(-x+y+z) + \sin(x-y+z) + \sin(x+y-z) \right)$$
$$\cos x \cos y \cos z = \frac{1}{4} \left( \cos(x+y+z) + \cos(-x+y+z) + \cos(x-y+z) + \cos(x+y-z) \right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A+B+C=(2n+1)\pi,$

$\sin A+\sin B+\sin C=2\sin\dfrac{A+B}2\cos\dfrac{A-B}2+2\sin\dfrac C2\cos\dfrac C2$

Now $\sin\dfrac{A+B}2=\sin\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi-C}2=(-1)^n\cos\dfrac C2$

and $\cos\dfrac{A+B}2=\cos\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi-C}2=(-1)^n\cos\dfrac C2$

$\implies2\sin\dfrac{A+B}2\cos\dfrac{A-B}2+2\sin\dfrac C2\cos\dfrac C2$

$=2(-1)^n\cos\dfrac C2\cos\dfrac{A-B}2+2(-1)^n\cos\dfrac{A+B}2\cos\dfrac C2$

$=2(-1)^n\cos\dfrac C2\left(\cos\dfrac{A-B}2+\cos\dfrac{A+B}2\right)$

$$\implies\sin A+\sin B+\sin C=4(-1)^n\cos\dfrac A2\cos\dfrac B2\cos\dfrac C2$$
if $A+B+C=(2n+1)\pi$

Here $n=0,1$

Answer (score 0):

Using $\sin^3{\theta} = \frac{1}{4}(3\sin{\theta}-\sin{3\theta})$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
& \sin^3{A}+\sin^3{B}+\sin^3{C} \\
&= \frac{3}{4}\left(\sin A + \sin B + \sin C\right) - \frac{1}{4}\left(\sin 3A + \sin 3B + \sin 3C\right) \\
&= \frac{3}{4}\left[2\sin{\frac{A+B}{2}}\cos{\frac{A-B}{2}} + 2\sin{\frac{C}{2}}\cos{\frac{C}{2}}\right] - \frac{1}{4}\left[2\sin{\frac{3A+3B}{2}}\cos{\frac{3A-3B}{2}}+2\sin{\frac{3C}{2}}\cos{\frac{3C}{2}}\right] \\
&= \frac{3}{4}\left[2\sin{\frac{C}{2}}\left(\cos{\frac{A-B}{2}} - \cos{\frac{A+B}{2}}\right)\right]+\frac{1}{4}\left[2\sin{\frac{3C}{2}\left(\cos{\frac{3A-3B}{2}}-\cos{\frac{3A+3B}{2}}\right)}\right] \\
&= \boxed{3\sin{\frac{A}{2}}\sin{\frac{B}{2}}\sin{\frac{C}{2}} - \sin{\frac{3A}{2}}\sin{\frac{3B}{2}}\sin{\frac{3C}{2}}}
\end{align*}
$QED.$